# C variable and memory problems

Tags: c, json, sockets, buffer

I have problem with my code somehow variable receiver_buffer gets some data from json_packet or from uu in function external_auth_format_packet.

Here you can see in the log:

```
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: userauth_external: DEBUG: socket_path: /tmp/auth.sock
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: userauth_external: DEBUG: json_packet: {"user": "root", "key": "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDwHDG/TpoUDts9CFrUWh6eoOlPcQYTLIpkF1udDaRZMsdZSZyDsWO5otqrUiQuVLFBXKa4CMiYBJIll2Ye/ZMWjbWd6mkrhE/u4Ha+DS6wyoza3mgn4ekDYxHqzk6/9kVnNtdh+sw3h0OwhkJJG/fAGzGFZhaV5bRS8f9u6pxIKTdmUfozkfe/QhYlFS9gaFnlK2rn8efK1oeNL00YBEcFLVeFdFqU9xuTOrHIQuOHxEynF/zekJ69D1MDhLZDhzq7mfy00wOnS51Q0gxZUdBiFr0ahuD/WrxKgwYunAsp1hD22+WU89vmoPtonWE7a6hTeZtz6Mb0YPfmRwz+CaR1", "type": "ssh-rsa"}
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: userauth_external: DEBUG: sent json_packet to server
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: userauth_external: DEBUG: receiver_buffer memory allocation
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: userauth_external: DEBUG: recv has received: {"status":1,"command":"command='./gitserve' "}
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: userauth_external: DEBUG: copying from tmp_buffer to receiver_buffer
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: userauth_external: DEBUG: finished receiving data from socket
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: error: userauth_external: ERROR: Unable to load parmaters! error: on line 1: end of file expected near 'rUWh'\n
Sep 26 12:35:07 ubuntu sshd[58912]: error: userauth_external: ERROR: response {"status":1,"command":"command='./gitserve' "}rUWh6eoOlPcQYTLIpkF1udDaRZMsdZSZyDsWO5otqrUiQuVLFBXKa4CMiYBJIll2Ye/ZMWjbWd6mkrhE/u4Ha+DS6wyoza3mgn4ekDYxHqzk6/9kVnNtdh+sw3h0OwhkJJG/fAGzGFZhaV5bRS8f9u6pxIKTdmUfozkfe/QhYlFS9gaFnlK2rn8efK1oeNL00YBEcFLVeFdFqU9xuTOrHIQuOHxEynF/zekJ69D1MDhLZDhzq7mfy00wOnS51Q0gxZUdBiFr0ahuD/WrxKgwYunAsp1hD22+WU89vmoPtonWE7a6hTeZtz6Mb0YPfmRwz+CaR1
```

from the socket receiver_buffer receives data

```
{"status":1,"command":"command='./gitserve' "}
```

but then jansson tries to parse the data it seeas data which don't belong to that variable

```
{"status":1,"command":"command='./gitserve' "}rUWh6eoOlPcQYTLIpkF1udDaRZMsdZSZyDsWO5otqrUiQuVLFBXKa4CMiYBJIll2Ye/ZMWjbWd6mkrhE/u4Ha+DS6wyoza3mgn4ekDYxHqzk6/9kVnNtdh+sw3h0OwhkJJG/fAGzGFZhaV5bRS8f9u6pxIKTdmUfozkfe/QhYlFS9gaFnlK2rn8efK1oeNL00YBEcFLVeFdFqU9xuTOrHIQuOHxEynF/zekJ69D1MDhLZDhzq7mfy00wOnS51Q0gxZUdBiFr0ahuD/WrxKgwYunAsp1hD22+WU89vmoPtonWE7a6hTeZtz6Mb0YPfmRwz+CaR1`
```

the source code of the function
http://pastebin.com/P7WnhsqX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
memcpy(receiver_buffer + total_received_chars, tmp_buffer, received_chars);
```

You're copying received_chars bytes, which is string length - it doesn't including terminating '\0' byte. Later, when you're trying to use it - you have your string + rest of the buffer, because you don't know how much you need to read.

Comment: which question did you answer? In his question I cant see anything what hes doing.

Comment: Ah grace period edit... When I first read his answer, there was no link to code, nevermind

Comment: so how to add that \0 to the end?

Comment: How have you coded all this if you don't know? o_O Anyway, change it to `received_chars+1`. Maybe i should add 'watch for overflow', but i wouldn't.